# I don't really understand why am i having a NaN result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value on the td. but i don't really understand why i'm having a NaN value, but if i change the value of blueJeansPrice = 1000 and blueJeansQty = 10, on the script it successfully alerts me the total.

HTML:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td id="blueJeans" value="Blue Jeans">Blue Jeans</td>
    <td id="blueJeansPrice" value="1000">1000</td>
    <td id="blueJeansQty" value="10">10</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show Report</button>
```

JS:

```
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
    var blueJeansPrice = parseInt($('#blueJeansPrice').val());
    var blueJeansQty = parseInt($('#blueJeansQty').val());
    var blueJeansTotal = blueJeansPrice * blueJeansQty;

    alert(blueJeansTotal);
})
```

Comment: the value attribute doesn't work in a TD element, only in inputs

Comment: if you need to have the value in the tag and you don't want to get the innerHTML, you can try adding `data-value="1000"` and get it with `$("td").data('value')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML element `<td>` doesn't support the `value` attribute. This attribute is used only in `input` elements.

When you try to access it trough `val()`, jQuery tries to access the element `.value` with native javascript, but it won't be there (because it's not an `HTMLInputElement`).

If you need to have the value in the tag and you don't want to get it using `innerHTML`, you can try adding `data-value="1000"` and get it with `$("td").data('value')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use $ele.html()

```
var blueJeansPrice = parseInt($('#blueJeansPrice').html())
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an `innerHTML()` method

Comment: Ohh! i got confused with Javascript function, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I think jquery uses `.html()` instead

Comment: and `.text()` will also return the contents but only the text and not the HTML tags